# how to replace the diminished chord in a key to write a good song without a diminished chord (for example e diminished to F)?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Is there a way to compose without the dimished chord yet still use E? I've tried for example usuing E minor but it sounded displaced in the key of F major.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "use E" as a pitch as opposed to a chord, you can always harmonize that E (scale-degree 7) with a V chord, which in the key of F would be a C-major (or a C7) chord. This is very common in all Western styles.

Another option, albeit one that would take a bit more work, would be E major moving to F major. But this often suggests a brief move towards A as opposed to the global tonic of F.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're thinking about the chord based on ^7 of the key of F - Edim.

There are other chords which could well come into play to include that E note. Am, C, C7, F▵, A7, F♯7 would all contain said E note. The first four of which are diatonic if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Diminished chords can have many functions, so there is no universal way to exchange them with something else.

However, one very common use, which seems to be your case, is when a diminished chord substitutes a dominant, or dominant b9 chord. As Richard wrote, Edim, that is E-G-Bb may substitute C7 chord, which is C-E-G-Bb – the last three notes are the same. Then, if you're looking for a less dissonant sound, you can replace C7 with C (C-E-G).

More general, Edim7, that is E-G-Bb-Db, may substitute the following chords (some notes need to be enharmonically respelled, in bold):

- C7b9: C-E-G-Bb-Db
- Eb7b9: E7b-G-Bb-Db-**Fb**
- F#7b9: F#-**A#**-**C#**-E
- A7b9: A-**C#**-E-G-Bb